# Removing the existing context menus from legendlayeractions QGIS 2.6.1 using python

Tags: pyqgis, python-2.7, qgis-2.6

```
a = QAction( u"My Action", iface1.legendInterface() )
iface1.legendInterface().addLegendLayerAction( a, u"My Plugin Menu", u"id1", QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer, True )   #adds action
iface1.legendInterface().removeLegendLayerAction(a) #removes action
```

removes user made actions . I want to take out all the inbuilt context menu actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since QGIS 2.4 you can use [QgsLayerTreeView](http://qgis.org/api/2.6/classQgsLayerTreeView.html) for that.

Remove all Layers Panel (legend) context menu actions:

```
ltv = iface.layerTreeView()
ltv.setMenuProvider( None )
```

Remove all and add only your own action: see [Display of context menu section](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2015/01/30/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-3/) by Martin Dobias.

Comment: can we have different actions for different layers?

Comment: You set a menu provider for the whole layer tree, but have a look at Martin's post (second link in my answer), there you see you could easily set specific actions for vectors, other actions for rasters, etc. Everything depends on your use case, as always.

Comment: can u please give an example for setting different actions for vectors ,rasters,etc

Comment: Please ask a new question in GIS.SE for that, then I could post an answer.

Comment: ya sure ,@ Germán Carrillo

Comment: can we bring back the default menu provider (because I have some hide/show functionality to be implemented) ?

Comment: Don't really understand what you intend to do, but before you overwrite the menu provider calling ltv.setMenuProvider( None ), you could get the QGIS menu provider calling qgisMenuProvider = ltv.menuProvider(), so you'll have it in qgisMenuProvider when you need it.

Comment: qgis is crashing on implementing this