# Setting different context menu actions for each layer type with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, table-of-contents, context-menu

I want to set different actions(context menu) for vectors,rasters,etc .

```
class MyMenuProvider(QgsLayerTreeViewMenuProvider):
def __init__(self, view):
    QgsLayerTreeViewMenuProvider.__init__(self)
    self.view = view

  def createContextMenu(self):
    if not self.view.currentLayer():
      return None
    m = QMenu()
    m.addAction("Show Attribute Table", self.openAttributeTable)
    return m

  def openAttributeTable(self):
    #iface1.openFeatureForm(iface1.activeLayer(), feature, False)
    iface1.showAttributeTable(iface1.activeLayer())
```

then using it as

```
 view = iface1.layerTreeView()
 provider = MyMenuProvider(view)
 view.setMenuProvider(provider)
```

But this sets menu provider for all layers , I want to have different actions for different layers

Comment: what did you tried so far and where did you get stuck? if needing help to solve it programming wise. please provide a sample of your own code

Comment: I have set menu provider to entire layer tree using   https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247470/removing-the-existing-context-menus-from-legendlayeractions-qgis-2-6-1-using-pyt/247497#247497 but want to set different actions for different layers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can always have a look at [how QGIS does it](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/ce4a2519c1561887617e67618b29e519e161dcce/src/app/qgsapplayertreeviewmenuprovider.cpp#L99) to get an idea.

In your case, you can use a conditional expression to evaluate the layer type. If current layer is a vector you add certain actions, if not, you add others.

This is a basic example (see the `createContextMenu` function):

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QMenu
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsRasterLayer
from qgis.gui import QgsLayerTreeViewMenuProvider

class MyMenuProvider(QgsLayerTreeViewMenuProvider):

    def __init__(self, view):
        QgsLayerTreeViewMenuProvider.__init__(self)
        self.view = view
        self.defaultActions = view.defaultActions()

    def createContextMenu(self):
        if not self.view.currentLayer():
            return None
        m = QMenu()
        m.addAction("Open layer properties", self.openLayerProperties)
        m.addSeparator()

        if type(self.view.currentLayer()) == QgsVectorLayer:
            m.addAction("Show Feature Count", self.featureCount)
            m.addAction("Another vector-specific action", self.vectorAction)
        elif type(self.view.currentLayer()) == QgsRasterLayer:
            m.addAction("Zoom 100%", self.zoom100)
            m.addAction("Another raster-specific action", self.rasterAction)
        return m

    def openLayerProperties(self):
        iface.showLayerProperties(self.view.currentLayer())

    def featureCount(self):
        self.defaultActions.actionShowFeatureCount().trigger()

    def vectorAction(self):
        pass

    def zoom100(self):
        iface.actionZoomActualSize().trigger()

    def rasterAction(self):
        pass

view = iface.layerTreeView()
provider = MyMenuProvider(view)
view.setMenuProvider(provider)
```

Which produces:

[image]