# How to get default QGIS context menu back after customizing it once?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2.6, python-2

I have created custom legend Layer context menu using

```
    class MyMenuProvider(QgsLayerTreeViewMenuProvider):
        def __init__(self, view):
            QgsLayerTreeViewMenuProvider.__init__(self)
            self.view = view

        def createContextMenu(self):
            if not self.view.currentLayer():
                return None
            m = QMenu()
            if type(self.view.currentLayer()) == QgsVectorLayer:
                m.addAction("Show Attribute Table",self.openAttributeTable)
            elif type(self.view.currentLayer()) == QgsRasterLayer:
                pass
            return m

       def openAttributeTable(self):
           self.attributeTable=attributeTableDialog()
           self.attributeTable.show()
```

but want to get the default context menu back (already provided by QGIS)!

Comment: I guess you could make use of the [QgsLayerTreeViewDefaultActions](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeViewDefaultActions.html) class.

Comment: eventually will have to use  QgsLayerTreeViewDefaultActions  only (i.e. recreating all actions from the above class) I thought if there was other way .Anyways, I implemented it as mentioned in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250139/setting-different-context-menu-actions-for-each-layer-type-with-pyqgis/250170