# Remove "Save As" from QGIS Context Menu Using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt

I want to remove an existing option ("Save As") from context menu of QGIS layer, what I have found so far is, to add new action in the `LegendItems`, or overwrite completely with new options. But could not find any option using that I would be able to remove an existing default Context menu option.

What I have also seen that there is **menuProvider()** method available, but could not get any details with this method.

How can I remove existing "Save As" option from the context menu of QGIS?

Comment: for remove all options and add a custom options check this : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/250170/49538

Comment: I have already seen that, what is am looking for is to remove only one action of existing Context menu.

Comment: I make a draft by only work the first click,i think that any actions is not posible deleted.You cand replicate this contextMenu ,but not all action have python method in QGIS Api

Comment: How can i replicate all of the default Actions ?

Comment: Check this example https://github.com/valheran/QDriller/blob/d19882c08d9ce6abe321dd5072d782e902888755/QDrillerPlugin/qdriller_dialog.py#L1564 and https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsLayerTreeViewDefaultActions.html  but not all action have method

Answer (score 3):

You need override the current context Menu, using your custom class

Minimal sample code for remove "**Export**" Option

```
from qgis.gui import QgsLayerTreeViewMenuProvider

ltv = iface.layerTreeView()
mp=ltv.menuProvider()
cm = mp.createContextMenu()

for action in cm.actions():
    # Need text value ,this object not have ObjectName
    if action.text() == "Exportar":
        cm.removeAction(action);
    #print (action.objectName())

class CustomMenuProvider(QgsLayerTreeViewMenuProvider):

  def __init__(self, view, actions):
    QgsLayerTreeViewMenuProvider.__init__(self)
    self.view = view
    self.defaultActions = actions

  def createContextMenu(self):
    if not self.view.currentLayer():
      return None
    m = QMenu()
    m.addActions(self.defaultActions)
    return m


provider = CustomMenuProvider(ltv, cm.actions())
ltv.setMenuProvider(provider)
```

Answer (score -3):

Navigate "Settings => Interface Customization" and disable "mActionSaveProjectAs" in the "Menus/mProjectMenu".

Comment: That is option to disable QGIS's project, but not the layer, is that ?