# QGIS contextual menu overriding

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I would like to override the default contextual menu in QGIS 3 in the ToC.

I've created a class that inherit from `QgsLayerTreeViewMenuProvider`.

```
from qgis.gui import QgsLayerTreeViewMenuProvider
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QMenu

class LayerTreeViewMenuProvider(QgsLayerTreeViewMenuProvider):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def createContextMenu(self):
        menu = QMenu()
        menu.addAction('Test', lambda : print('test'))
        return menu
```

This code works well but I would like to get in all cases (right click in ToC or to a vector layer, raster layer, ...) the default contextual menu to adapt it. So I've made :

```
def createContextMenu(self):
    menu = super().createContextMenu()
    return menu
```

That doesn't work, I've got a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: Have you already seen [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/250139/setting-different-context-menu-actions-for-each-layer-type-with-pyqgis/250170#250170)?

Comment: @GermánCarrillo I've already seen this answer but it doesn't make what i want.I would like to modify the menu. With this solution, i must to rewrite all the code of this method *QgsAppLayerTreeViewMenuProvider::createContextMenu()* in python. I only want to override this menu created to add an entry in all cases

Comment: You cannot modify the menu, since the menu has to be built each time it is called. Nonetheless, you can use the default actions of the layer tree, like in this example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/267613/remove-save-as-from-qgis-context-menu-using-pyqgis

Comment: @GermánCarrillo Thanks for your answer. If I use the super () method in my class. Should I be able to retrieve the QMenu object? In this case, I could overload it for my needs ?

Comment: No, you can't, because the menu object is built in the `createContextMenu()` method, and that is exactly what you need to overwrite to add your own action (see the ['More about the view' section here](https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2015/01/30/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-3/)). Additionally, you can see how QGIS devs do it [here](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/ce4a2519c1561887617e67618b29e519e161dcce/src/app/qgsapplayertreeviewmenuprovider.cpp#L48).